# DateTime.ParseExact returns wrong date for the 'dd/MM/yyyy h:mm tt' format

Tags: c#, date, datetime

I need to convert datetime from `MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt` format to the `dd/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss tt`

**My code**

```
 var date = ((DateTime)model.WorkshopDate).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss tt");

 var resultDate = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dd/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

In result `date = 25/12/2017 12:00:00 AM`

But `resultDate = 12/25/2017 12:00:00 AM` .

How can i parse it right?

Comment: are you looking at it from the debugger?

Comment: Your description of your problem and code do not match up! Your code creates a string representation of a date as `dd/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss tt` and then attempts to parse the exact same format. A `DateTime` object has no "format" - only the string representation of it does

Comment: The value is correctly parsed, but may displayed with wrong format - i.e. depends on regional settings on your machine.

Comment: Why?  You only have to convert strings.  If a date is already a DateTime object it is always stored the same in any computer.  The string conversion base on the County settings of the computer. When sending data between computers it normally uses the DateTime object and not the string.

Comment: @jdweng Correct! this is where many make mistakes haha

Comment: Then why are all the experts giving stupid responses?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking at the object in the debugger which is a datetime object and not a display version of your date.

Example:

```
var theDate = DateTime.UtcNow;

var date = theDate.ToString( "dd/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss tt" );
var resultDate = DateTime.ParseExact( date, "dd/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture );

Console.WriteLine(date == resultDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss tt"));//Returns true
```

As you see they are the same dates so just `.ToString()` it to whatever format you need when displaying.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to convert it to a `String` and back to a `DateTime`. The resulting `DateTime` object should have the same Date. You just need to convert it when you want to display it somewhere:

```
((DateTime)model.WorkshopDate).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss tt");
```

Comment: In fact, this line `var resultDate = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dd/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` is useless - `DateTime` value presentation depends on current regional setting if it not converted to string.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto in that code `date` is a string, not a DateTime!

Comment: No, it is not useless. It expects a string in the given format. If that is the case and the seperate values in that format match the restrictions of DateTime it will give you a DateTime object representing the value of the input string. It' absolutely valid.

Answer (score 0):

here

```
var date = ((DateTime)model.WorkshopDate).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss tt");
```

you are implicitly asking to display the date in "dd/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss tt"

```
var resultDate = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dd/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

here system default format is using to display the date.

if you want to display both as same

```
Console.WriteLine(date);
Console.WriteLine(resultDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss tt"));
```